# jquery - how can I see a wildcard in my ID selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To hide a bunch of different content around the page initially I do...

```
$('#objective_details, #time_estimate_details, #team_members_details, #resources_details').hide();
```

Is there a way to do some sort of wildcard like

```
$('#*_details').hide();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use an [attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('[id$="_details"]')
```

This is much slower than selecting by id though.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS classes. For each tag or element with "details" in it, apply a class:

```
<p class="details"> ... </p>
<div class="details"> ... </div>
<section class="details"> ... </section>
```

Then do:

```
$('.details').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this is personal homework though and I want to find a wildcard solution

Comment: Bah. :) I have mixed feelings about homework with requirements that aren't best practice, but I guess you can't really do anything about that! The "attribute ends with" selector, as has been posted, is what you want, but is less standard. But I guess you gotta do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 2):

`$('[id$=_details]').hide();`

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('div[id$="_details"]'); // faster I suppose

// Following also works using "." (-may be as of only jQuery 1.6 +)
jQuery('div.[id$="_details"]')
```